# plugin to upload to youtube via wordpress

Tags: admin, plugin-recommendation, wp-admin, youtube

before you say it, i know that in most situations it's *easier* to do this the other way around (i.e. upload via yt site then embed) but i *need* a plugin to upload/manage yt videos via the wordpress admin interface.

ive scanned through the plugin directory but cant see any good options.

can anyone suggest anything worthy?

hopefully something that uses the youtube api:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following plugin for uploading video to YouTube from your WordPress site.

[YouTube Uploader](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-uploader/)

The plugin description says:

> This plugin allows you to upload your videos on youtube without
>   leaving wordpress. Useful especially for video blogging sites.

Though you need to enter your developer key and choose the method of authentication in YouTube uploader settings page of the plugin in order to upload video into YouTube.